# How do I automatically go to the next field after entering data on a field using filemaker pro

Tags: filemaker

I am very new to filemaker pro and I'm using scanner to scan ID cards, I want a way where after I scan the ID's, it will automatically go to the next field.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My FileMaker solution does exactly this.

1. you program the Barcode scanner to append a carriage return at the end of the barcode when it scans it.
2. in FileMaker, set an onObjectSave script trigger for the field where you are inputting the barcode which will trigger when you exit the field. In this script you would run what ever code you want to process the barcode. Your script can also Go to Next field.

OnObjectKeystoke that someone has suggested does not work properly and you will have issues with it where it sometimes triggers and sometimes it doesn't. I found it to be unreliable.

Comment: "*OnObjectKeystoke that someone has suggested does not work properly*" Yes, it does. If you are having issues with it, then *you* are not using it properly. Please don't start rumors.

Comment: Starting rumours? Not using it correctly? Yeah ok if it makes you feel better.

Comment: The appropriate answer would be to post a link to the bug report you have submitted to FMI. But I guess it makes *you* feel better to shoot the messenger...

Comment: Used the onObjectKeystroke method with barcode scanners in a commercial solution used by 1000's of people and it would randomly fail at times. I'm guessing the barcode scanner enters the value too quickly and onObjectKeystroke fails to keep up as it triggers for every character scanned. Solution was to use onObjectSave.

Comment: Nothing fails randomly - at least not in the realm of computing. In any case, you can only use OnObjectSave if your scanner tries to save the field. If it doesn't (and cannot be programmed to do so), then OnObjectKeystroke is your **only** option - and any timing issues need to be worked out within the triggered script.

Comment: Hence my advice to program the barcode scanner to enter a carriage return

Comment: That's a good advice - I have advised the same thing a week before you have posted your answer...

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't your scanner output a "postamble" character to signify the end of the scan? Ideally, you would program it to be the tab (ASCII 9) character, so the scanner would completely emulate a human user.

Return/Enter characters can also be used in the same way - if you set the field/s in question to "Go to next object using [one of these]" in the Inspector.

Less conveniently, but you can use any other character in conjuntion with a script triggered OnObjectKeystroke.

This is assuming you really *want* the cursor to move to the next field at the end of a scan. To me, it sounds like you are scanning multiple instances of the same *entity* - and therefore each scan should create a new **record**.

Comment: And how exactly do I do that? @michael.hor257k

Comment: What exactly is "that"?